# How do I splice ranges in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a schedule management system which loads a person's work schedule into an array, and then the user is allowed to "inject" a new shift within that day. There are a couple of rules the code must follow, of course, and they are:

1. There must be no gaps between existing shifts and the added item. This means the added item's end time must be equal to or greater than the first item's start time, and the added item's start time must be equal to or less than the last item's end time.
2. The added shift must overwrite any existing shifts which occur during it's time frame. Essentially, it needs to splice itself into the array, but I'm unsure of how to do so using the .splice() method.
3. Any affected time blocks must be truncated/compressed to accommodate the new item. For example, if there is an existing time block which is an hour in duration, and we inject a 10 minute block into that beginning 20 minutes in, it would result in the first 20 minute portion of the original block, followed by the 10 minute added item, followed by the remainder of the original block. Added items must also be able to overlap other time blocks as well. So if we add a three hour block that covers 4 other time blocks (or starts/stops within them!) it must overwrite each of those.

This seems like a simple enough task, because basically it's just splicing ranges, but I don't know how to splice ranges in JavaScript.

Here's the code I've written to implement these rules so far:

```
var obj = {
    start: '',
    end: '',
};
var objArray = [];
var tmpArray = [];
var finalArray = [];
objArray.push({start: "12:00", end: "12:45"});
objArray.push({start: "12:45", end: "1:00"});
objArray.push({start: "1:00", end: "1:30"});
objArray.push({start: "1:30", end: "2:30"});
// added object
obj.start = "12:00";
obj.end = "12:10";
for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) { tmpArray.push(objArray[i]); }
//tmpArray = objArray; // preserve the original array
objArray.push(obj);
console.clear();
console.log("%o", objArray);
objArray.sort(function(a, b) { var x = a.start; var y = b.start; return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0)); });
// sanity check
if (obj.start >= obj.end){
    console.log('Time logic is invalid.');
    return false;
}
if (obj.end < tmpArray[0].start) {
    console.log('There is a gap before the first item.');
    return false;
}
if (obj.start > tmpArray[tmpArray.length - 1].end){
    console.log('There is a gap after the last item.');
    return false;
}

// Now for the fun stuff...
for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++){
    var tmpobj = objArray[i];
    if (tmpobj.start == obj.start && tmpobj.end == obj.end){ // find our inserted object
        index = i;
        console.log('<<< obj injected: %s - %s [%d] >>>', obj.start, obj.end, index);
        if (index == 0){ // is first item, start time was less than first item's start time
            finalArray.push(obj);
            if (obj.end == tmpArray[0].start){
                finalArray.push(tmpArray[0]); // item insertion was a complete prepend...
            } else if (obj.end >= tmpArray[tmpArray.length - 1].end){
                console.log('entire array is consumed'); // item covers entire shift...
            } else {
                // This code is reached when obj start time is before or equal to first item
                console.log('obj <= tmpArray[0].start, end > tmpArray[0].start');
            }
        } else {
            if (obj.start == tmpArray[tmpArray.length - 1].end){
                console.log('Item added at end of shift');
                finalArray.push(tmpArray[i - 1]);
                finalArray.push(obj);
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log('obj tested: %s - %s [%d]', tmpobj.start, tmpobj.end, i);
        if (obj.start > tmpobj.end) {
            finalArray.push(tmpobj);
        }
        if (obj.end < tmpobj.start) {
            finalArray.push(tmpobj);
        }
    }
// now iterate through array and combine like terms (activity type)
}
for (var i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++){
    console.log('%d) s: %s, e: %s', i, finalArray[i].start, finalArray[i].end);
}
```

How do I splice ranges in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider your time blocks in term of *start* and *end* separately. I conceptually think of it as a linked list, which you can implement as an Array. With a special requirement that each node in the list must follow the order of `START_TIME -> END_TIME` and never have 2 `START_TIME` or 2 `END_TIME` nodes adjacent to each other. And any in between (free time blocks) is also defined by a `START_TIME` and `END_TIME` node.

`S`is `START_TIME`

`E` is `END_TIME`

The array of valid time blocks may look like this `[S1, E1, S2, E2, S3 ,E3]`

So then when coding the logic to insert new blocks of time, you find your desired block by going to the appropriate `START_TIME` node for your new timeblock, then "splice" by creating an `END_TIME E*` node and a new `START_TIME S-NEW` node marking the beginning of your new block.

`[S1, E1 ,S2 ,E* ,S-NEW, E2, S3, E3]`

Then you may define the ending time by creating `END_TIME` node if necessary (remove old `END_TIME E2` and creating a "free" block),

`[S1, E1, S2, E*, S-NEW, E-NEW, S-FREE, E-FREE, S3, E3]`

or reuse the old `END_TIME E2` node that you "spliced" earlier if they end at the same time

`[S1, E1, S2, E*, S-NEW, E2, S3, E3]`

The reason you're hurting your brain at the end is because your code is doing too much all at once. I suggest breaking it up into functions, here are some suggestions:

```
canStart(time)
canEnd(time)
insertBlock(startBlock, endBlock)
removeBlock(startBlock, endBlock)
```